# Is it possible to reference a ParameterExpression inside Linq query syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve, I'm not sure if it is even possible or if I am going about this all wrong.

```
Expression<T, bool> UseDataContext<T>(Expression<Func<DataContext, T, bool>> expr, Expression dataContextExpr){
    // use ExpressionVisitor and return new LambaExpression
}    

Expression<Func<DataContext, Foo, bool>> fooFilterExpr = (db, foo) 
    => db.FilteredFoos.Any(vf => vf.FooId == foo.Id);

Expression<Func<DataContext, Bar, bool>> barExpr = (db) => (
    from bar in db.Bars
    join foo in db.Foos.Where(UseDataContext(fooFilterExpr, ?db Expression?))
    select bar
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, basically. That isn't something that is available in the syntax. You'd have to create all the lambdas manually for that.

Suggestion: take a simpified but working example, and run it through `https://sharplab.io/` specifying C# as the "Results" - that will give you the manual code to do that, including the `ParameterExpression`, which you can then use to replace it with a manually written version; [example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGAdAGQEsA7ARwG4BYAKHS2ytsxwJNNwFEAPABwTihRCAe2JRGNFACYMAEQgwIAYVHwuMDBgDeNTZpQBmDAEkAigFdEATwjAANnAA8AIQgIAfBlcIoGALyexOZ2dox6WEZmlgg29k4AYsLCnonCvgEYQSGMAL6SMt7aunqGGCQaxgAm2gDmcDDkUPXkedSt0hipRdThpeUm1Vp1DU0Nra2SRh1K3b1TACwYALIAFACUs+F63HwCQqKOKACsjvKKKsRqMAA0Xm63wEl27p7AbjsI/hgrlcAPGxkVsUtlsAGYIYRgDBvT4kDC/XDeKDAkF6ABWwjhoKSZWI8OAuFSUFwAHUABaIOArABe/k8MAQlg2omhblwVQwcFI5ggdl82OE7MqKNRGCaDgAxhoYSK9GtcABBYhWdZhPTjGhAA). Then replace the bits that you need to.

I never said it would be pretty...

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I thought that might be the case, I was hoping to avoid doing this as the Linq query syntax is clearly much more readable.